# I feel like I am already relaxing/relaxed

Tags: word-usage, meaning, passive-voice, active-voice

There are a husband and wife talking about something.

> H: Do you reckon it is any good?
>
> W: I hope so.
>
> H: Oh, it's good. It's perfect. Just as I remember it.
>
> W: Really?
>
> H: Well done. Actually it is better.
>
> W: I feel like I am already (relaxing/relaxed)

Is "relaxing" or "relaxed" better here? What is the difference between the two expressions (passive voice and active voice)?

Comment: Is the 'thing' they are talking about something to help people to relax?

Comment: Yes, it is right.